# Unlimited swivel connector

Tags: connector

I am looking for a rotating connector over which I can communicate and power devices.  The connector must be able to rotate for a minumum of 1080 degrees.  The scope of what I am trying to do is make a quick release on my racing sim wheel, which has a bunch of buttons and displays on it.  I found some connectors with unlimited degrees of rotation for wind generators, [[here]](http://www.mercotac.com/html/wind_energy.html), but they don't really support quick release.

Comment: When you say "quick release", do you mean that it should be easy to disconnect or that it will disconnect if pulled apart?

Comment: yes something like this http://www.momo88.com/sitepix/products/momosnapoff.jpg

Comment: http://www.swivelelectricalconnector.com/rotating_electrical_connectors/swivel_electrical_connector_best.php

Comment: If you can power the removable part from a battery this would be a nice application for a kind of infrared system.

Answer (score 3):

For 1080 degrees (3 rotations). I would not bother with a slip ring mechanism. They are fairly fragile and often you get intermittent contacts. I would just use fairly flexible cabling and a standard connector. Just have the wheel plug in the a rotating plate on the column and put the connector in rotation plate.

Comment: Digi-Key sells prefabricated flat-flex cable in a variety of lengths.  This is what printers use to connect to the moving printhead.

Comment: +1.  That's pretty much what I was going to say.  Slipping connections make a mess of digital data.  Getting reliable communication will require lots of filtering and be slow as a result.  The right kind of coiled up wire can handle 3 rotations.

Answer (score 2):

Neat. Could you do it with a single 3.5mm, 3-channel/line audio jack, right in the middle? Communicate serially, then power and ground on the other two. (Can actually use 2-channel/line, like the [1-Wire system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Wire), but may as well take the easy way out.)

If it's in danger of breaking, use a larger diameter TRS connector.

Comment: Thats a good idea, not sure how well an headphone connector will hold up from the rotation of the connection.  I was planning on doing some serial communication.  I say the compnay fanatec showing off their new Clubsport wheel in a youtube video.  You can clear see the connector in the middle of the quick release.  Still trying to decide if I want to put a microcontroller in the wheel or not so that would determine the number of pins I need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you looked at [these](http://www.mercotac.com/html/205.html) rotary contacts manufactured by the mercotac company. I know an application where they are used to transmit an audio signal to a [rotating speaker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leslie_speaker). The contact can be removed by hand; however, I don't know if these connectors have special limitations to cycles of operation or mechanical stress.

[image: mercotac type 205]